# Restful web service using @formparam to produce xml file(marshalling)

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I have a basic html form with a text box and a submit button
I am interested in creating a restful web service wherein I will be exposing a method
of MY EJB(from a working search based application) to retrieve values from the database..
I will be using the value entered in the text box as a  where clause of SQL query in the EJB method of my application.

I am new to restful service.
I want to generate a xml file on click of the submit button
Any suggestions..?

The IDE I am using is net beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *retrieve* data, a simple `GET` request should be enough.

**HTML form**

```html
<form action="/path/to/the/resource" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="query" id="query"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Query/>
</form>
```

**JAX-RS Resource**

```java
@Path("/path/to/the/resource")
public class MyResource {

  @GET
  @Produces("application/xml")
  public Response query(@QueryParam("query") String query) {
    // retrieve values from the database using the query
    MyJaxbAnnotatedDataClass result = ...;
    return Response.ok(result).build();
  }
}
```

**JAXB annotated class**

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class MyJaxbAnnotatedDataClass {
  // many fields, getters, setters with JAXB annotations
}
```